# A "triplet" with 4 notes in LPX

Tags: logic-pro, tuplet

I'm trying to sequence a piece of sheet music that has two quarter notes followed by two eighth notes; all four notes are tied together using a tuplet bracket (written as a triplet).

[image]

How can this be input using LPX's score authoring?

Comment: I don't even know if the god of the bible himself knows how that rhythm is to be played.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - even Cecilia could manage to play that ! It's not even tricky for mere mortals!

Answer (score 2):

1. Drag a triplet quarter note from the Part box onto the staff
2. Drag a tuplet object on this
3. A dialogue opens: set first dropdown to 3 (triplets) second dropdown to 2 (three triplets equal two non triplets) third dropdown to /4 (you want quarter notes) and **important**: check the very last check box: "Allow half values".
4. Click "OK"
5. Add another triplet quarter note
6. Add two more triplet 1/8 which is only possible because you checked "Allow half values"

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

What's LPX?

But that's not too complicated.  Would you be OK if it was a straight quarter-note triplet?  Three quarter-notes sharing the time normally taken by two?   Well, do that, but split the last two notes in half.

If quarter-notes get 960 'clicks',  two of them get 1920.   So a triplet quarter notes gets 1920/3, which is 640.   Half of one gets 320.

So, thinking in sequencer 'clicks', you want two notes of length 640, then two of length 320.

(Hope my maths is right :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I can do it in the step sequencer or the piano roll, but I want to be able to do it in the staff view (score view).   LPX=Logic Pro X

Comment: Are you saying that the Score Edit page in Logic WON'T accept triplet quarter notes, then editing one of them into two 8ths?

Comment: I just tried in Cubase.  I dont know the Score page very well (I use Sibelius for notation) and it wasn't very intuitive how to get that notation.  I succeeded by dropping into Key Edit and dragging the notes to the right lengths, after which Score Edit displayed exactly what we wanted! I'm sure it COULD have been done directly in Score Edit, and that Logic can too.